# What are the actual ms time values for Android's animTime constants?

Tags: android, animation, constants

Android includes

```
config_longAnimTime
config_mediumAnimTime
config_shortAnimTime
```

but the actual values identified by these constants don't make sense as milliseconds.  I'm sure they get compiled into useful values, and I can determine them with code, but I'm sure someone else knows the answer - and, more to the point, I'm sure other people will be looking for them.  So please post the actual values as an answer and save everyone a little bit of time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Current values (since 3.x):

- config_shortAnimTime=200
- config_mediumAnimTime=400
- config_longAnimTime=500

And the duration of the activity open/close and fragment open/close animations:

- config_activityShortDur=150
- config_activityDefaultDur=220

Comment: Thank you for the update!  I'm making this the new accepted answer.

Comment: The current values (or historical ones) may be found at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml

Answer (score 43):

Directly read the property:

```
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);
```

Don't use a hard-coded value: some devices provide an option to speed up animations: a hard-coded value would ignore that setting.

Answer (score 27):

Here we go:

```
config_longAnimTime   = 400
config_mediumAnimTime = 300
config_shortAnimTime  = 150
```

Comment: @JosephusVillarey it was a long time ago, but I believe I just wrote some code to print out the values.

Comment: i figured. that's what i did too. i wondered if you found it somewhere in android source.

Comment: Pro tip: Define an integer resource like `<integer name="slide_duration">@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime</integer>` then you get the android default speeds yet can still change it around for debugging

Comment: This is measured in ms?  If so, then 400 is less than half a second, hardly perceivable...

Comment: The tricky thing is that `config_activityShortDur` for example is now "private` through `@android:` so you actually have to check the source code to find the values.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using java code for create and start animation.
The default duration for a animation is 300

```
public class ValueAnimator extends Animator implements AnimationHandler.AnimationFrameCallback {
    ...
    // How long the animation should last in ms
    private long mDuration = 300;
}
```